# Searching a database table from a web form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want do a search in a sql table using a drop down menu.

For exmple, the user can chose color and then it will show all the items with that color.

Here is my code - I tried to use sql command with color red (rouge in French) it works; then I tried to use `$couleur`, it does not work.  can someone check my sql command please. thank you so much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="" method="post" action="enquete.php">
<select name="couleur">
   <option ></option>
  <option value="rouge">rouge</option>
  <option value="pink">pink</option>



</select>




</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit2" /> <br/>
</form>


</body>
</html>

<?php 

     //traitement pour decoulant couleur
    if (isset($_POST["couleur"]) && $_POST["couleur"]!="0"&& isset($_POST["submit"]) ){
        //connexion avec le serveur
        include_once("mesparametres.inc.php");
        //récupération données formulaire
        $couleur = $_POST["couleur"];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `poisson` WHERE `couleur` LIKE 'rouge'";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `poisson` WHERE `couleur` LIKE '\"$couleur\"'";
       $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());


        // Printing results in HTML

        echo "<table border='1' width='300'>\n";

         $count = 0;
            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
               echo "\t<tr>\n";
               foreach ($line as $col_value) {
                   echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
               }
               $count++;
               echo "\t</tr>\n";
            }

            echo "</table>\n";


        //fermeture connexion avec la BD
        mysql_close($idConnectDB); 
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: is this a typo? `isset($_POST["submit"])` ? When you use `name="submit2"` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: thanks, it works now, i used mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 3):

I would change the offending line to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM poisson WHERE couleur LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($couleur) . "%'";
```

Note that `LIKE` is a text search... If you want to only pull results where the column is exactly what is in `$couleur` you should replace LIKE with `=` and remove the percent signs (wild-card matching.)

Also note that I wrapped the `$couleur` variable inside the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function to protect from SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra quotes around `$couleur`.

Try this one:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `poisson` WHERE `couleur` LIKE '$couleur'";
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not a PHP guy, don't know how it's done there. Just spotted obvious mistake :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change this line:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `poisson` WHERE `couleur` LIKE '\"$couleur\"'";
```

to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `poisson` WHERE `couleur` LIKE '".$couleur."'";
```

Comment: @Pekka I'd say your comment on the question itself is enough. SQL injection is only one of many other basic design flaws in the script posted. Better get something for your cough! :)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `poisson` WHERE `couleur` LIKE '\"$couleur\"'";
```

would actually search for the value `"rouge"`, instead of the correct value `rouge`.

Change it to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `poisson` WHERE `couleur` LIKE '".$couleur."'";
```

However, this is prone to sql injection attacks. You should either switch to using prepared statements (see [PHPs PDO](http://php.net/pdo) for example) or at least use `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `poisson` ".
         "WHERE `couleur` LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($couleur)."'";
```